# trying to triangulate position from known access point strengths (dmb) (java)

Tags: java, triangulation

I have created a class which return the signal strength of 3 known access points (I also have the x and y co-ordinates of the access points) but now I have the problem of triangulating the position of the user. I have read numerous articles and even thesis on the matter but I can't make any sense out of the methods they are using. Would be very greatful if someone could help me out here. Thanks

Comment: Do you know the GPS coordinates of the access points?

Comment: yes I have them as well. I have placed them on a 2d map of the room so all I need help with is the triangulation method :) sorry I should have mentioned this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485370/wifi-position-triangulation