# how to calculate distance from 3 access point to do trilateration approach

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using android to scan distance between an access point to the phone to get indoor positioning using Wi-Fi trilateration approach.
I'm able to get distance from 1 access point which is the wifi currently connected in my phone. My first problem is now I do not know how to get distance from another 2 access point. Is there anyway that could let me calculate the distance without connecting to the access point? I'm restricted for using beacons by my lecturer, if there is any ways without using beacons please do let me know. I've done lots of research and couldn't get anything to help me solve this. Thanks in advance for the help, I really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485370/wifi-position-triangulation

Comment: For the problem fetching the RSSI values of non connected accesspoints : 
You will have to use the WifiMager to retrieve a list of scan results: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()

Each of these results contain a public int called level < -- that is your RSSI.

Comment: thanks it was a great help! now i able to detect and calculate the distance as well